# External Type for Type Checking without importing the external Type

Tags: python, import, typechecking

I want to annotate my code with a Type from an external library, without actually importing the external type. Currently I'm doing this:

```
from externalLibrary import ExternalType # Don't want this import

class MyClass:
         var: ExternalType
```

The application that brought this up was a python dataclass, and the external Type isn't always used. But importing it always happens, and it's slow.

Is there a way to avoid the slow import?

Comment: Maybe you could open the library and copy-paste the ExternalType class in your code?

Comment: That seems like it would produce an awful lot of clutter, not to mention you have to deal with all the external references in what you copied.
I suppose you could create a stub class, but I'm not sure how well that plays with type checking a larger programming. And it's still kinda inelegant.